# Boot guard verified failed

Tags: boot, bios, usb-flash-drive

I have an Asus VivoBook S14 S406U (runs Windows 10 64-bit) that run into this problem:

> boot guard verified failed
>   system will shutdown
>   press any key

I wanted to use a Kali Linux live USB in order to get some files. But I don't manage to access the boot menu.

I've also read something about this error on the internet, but nothing helped. 
Some say:

> That message is caused by a bad motherboard. It will need to be
>   replaced.

some say that this might be a BIOS problem.

So is there a way to make it boot from a USB? Or can I somehow access my files without altering the files?

Comment: Did this arrive after you updated the BIOS? If so, where did you download the BIOS from?

Comment: @harrymc No, I didn't update the BIOS.

Comment: Asus has this advice for entering the BIOS: "Press and hold the F2 button, then click the power button. DO NOT RELEASE the F2 button until the BIOS screen display". If you succeed entering the BIOS, check if in Advanced Mode of the you see a Tool Menu, where you have an "ASUS EZ Flash" option.

Comment: @harrymc Unfortunately, that didn't work. I've tried multiple ways to access the BIOS, but after the logo display, it goes right into `boot guard verified failed`.

Comment: What is your BIOS make and version?

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, but how am I supposed to find that out if I cannot access anything?

Comment: Don't you get any BIOS screen at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101127/discussion-between-grrigore-and-harrymc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong and your BIOS got corrupted and won't boot.
This also means that you cannot neither reset the BIOS nor re-install it.
The cause for the error is unknown, but is more often a power fluctuation.

You may find the right BIOS version to install on the webpage of
[ASUS VivoBook S14 S406UA BIOS & FIRMWARE](https://www.asus.com/me-en/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-S14-S406UA/HelpDesk_BIOS/).

Unfortunately, to reset the BIOS may require dangerous hardware manipulations that
I cannot advise to anyone who is not a computer technician.

It will take an ASUS-qualified workshop to reinstall this BIOS and to verify for
further damage. Unfortunately, that is my best advice.

Comment: So this is more likely to be a hardware related error?

Comment: A hardware-caused error. But not necessarily any hardware damage to the computer itself. It's possible that re-installing or resetting the BIOS will fix the problem.